# Invalid number input in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want the following Angular code (using Angular 12) to show "Illegal award number" when the input is invalid.

As you can see in the screenshot, when the number is -1 (smaller than the min value defined on the input), the div is shown as expected.

However, if I input some text such as `1-`, or an expression `3-4` and hover my mouse over it, the browser will tell me my input is not a valid number, **but the div is not shown (which means awardInputRef.invalid is false)**.

Why is that?

Here is the relevant code

```
<label class="form-label" for="awardInput">Award</label>
<input class="form-control" id="awardInput" type="number" min="0" max="10" step="0.1" [(ngModel)]="award"
  #awardInputRef="ngModel" />
<div *ngIf="awardInputRef.invalid">Illegal award number</div>
```

[image]

PS:

If I add `(blur)="onAwardBlur($event)"` to the award input and add a function in my component

```
onAwardBlur(event) {
    console.log(event);
}
```

then debug the code by log`event.target.validity.valid`, I will see it is `false`.

The code is available on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9arwwd?file=src/app/app.component.html). The Angular version there is 11, and the div does not show up even if I input `-1` there.

Comment: Can you put your code on stackblitz?

Comment: Or better yet, use the built-in [Stack Snippet functionality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers). @DrizzleX could you provide some example valid/invalid inputs for this field? Are you strictly wanting to allow only number > 0, or is `4-3` a valid input here?

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi I've put the code to stackblitz (but it does behave like what I have on my machine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As part of Angular version 12 only min and max directive are implemented that's why stackblitz version is not working.

You can workaround your issue using native Input element [ValidityState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState)

Define another one template variable on input element

```
<input class="form-control" id="awardInput" type="number" min="0" max="10" step="0.1" [(ngModel)]="award"
  #awardInputRef="ngModel" #inputRef />
```

Then you can add some custom validity something like this:

```
<div *ngIf="awardInputRef.invalid
|| inputRef.validity.badInput && (awardInputRef.dirty || awardInputRef.touched)
">Illegal award number</div>
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-68119404invalid-number-input-in-html?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: If you are wondering why angular validator stays valid even for invalid (1-) case. it's because angular use parseInt method internally for some manipulation due to which it's validity state stays valid. you can check source code here https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/validators.ts#L581

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just one question: “ As part of Angular version 12 only min and max directive are implemented that's why stackblitz version is not working.” do you mean only in Angular 12 it considers the min and max value specified on the input element? Because that is what I am seeing.

Comment: When we place min and max angular explicitly invoke min and max directive inorder to sync formcontrol validity. Prior to angualr 12 angular does not have any min and max directive, it's just native min and max attributes

Answer (score 0):

## input: -1

Your Using [ - ] this special character so the filed goes awardInputRef.invalid.
so div shown.

## input: 1-

Your using number first it goes awardInputRef.valid or something else but not awardInputRef.invalid .

so the div not shown in this case.

you just inspect the field and find the before after changes .